# React: Routing component in if/else block. Does it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to implement redirecting in the `render()` block to receive the possibility to redirect not logged users.

There is a workable code:
1)

```js
<Route exact path="/home">
    <Home/>
</Route>
```

But when I try to use if/else statement the code doesn't work - page doesn't open the Home.js component.

My attempts:

2)

```js
<Route exact path="/home"
    render={() => (loggedIn ? <Home /> : <Redirect to="/login" />)}
/>
```

3. 

```js
<Route exact path="/home">
    if(loggedIn){
        <Home/>
    } else {
        <Redirect to="/login" />
    }
</Route>
```

4. 

```js
const HomeRoute = ({ loggedIn }) => {
  if (loggedIn) {
    return <Home />;
  } else {
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }
};

<Route exact path="/home" render={() => <HomeRoute loggedIn={loggedIn} />} />
```

This is all that I found and figured out.

How to correctly call .js component in this case?

---

Additional info:

I am new in React and in general in the frontend, so I don't know on which side I have to look. As I understand, the issue is somewhere in another place. I will put here info from DevTools/Network tab, possibly it will be useful for more experienced developers:

1. The Network tab for positive case (1):

[image]

2. The Network tab for negative (2,3,4):

[image]

As I understand - this is impossible to use if/else statement there.
Does exist any another way to check or user is loggedIn (the token exist in localstore) and forward user to the different pages?

Comment: Check what version react-router you are using.
Also, check if you are wrapping your route with <Switch> in case v5, or <Routes>, if use v6

Comment: @ClusterH There is version: `react-router-dom": "^5.3.0"`. But also, please take to attention - the code works well without if/else statement. So versioning should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Form your statement as:

> condition ? (true html) : (false html)

```
<Route
  exact
  path="home"
  element={
    loggedIn ? (
      <Home />
    ) : (
      <Navigate replace to={"/login"} />
    )
  }
/>
```

Also be sure to get the correct paths defined on Routes

Comment: Thanks for your attention to my question. This solution also doesn't work. I have put additional information in my question, possibly it will be useful for understanding.

Comment: can you provide the whole code ?

Comment: there is: https://gitlab.com/hhrzc/dd45ui/-/tree/BAEL-03/frontend

Comment: check this out: https://dev.to/salehmubashar/conditional-routing-with-react-router-v6-229g

Comment: I am moving exactly in the same way. Only one difference - I use `Redirect` instead `Navigete` for Login page. But the `Home` page doesn't opened

Comment: And it works before I added if/else statement